# How to intercept outgoing request on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, request, intercept

Got two applications running on tomcat:

- Application1 (JSP)
- Application2 (Webservices)

I want to set request parameter (User object, with information about current user) that is going out of the Application1 and when this request gets to Application2 I want to retrieve the parameter and change some local configurations in Application2.

I know I can filter the incoming request in Application2 by using Filter, but how can I filter the outgoing request in Application1?

Comment: Tried to use tomcat custom valve, but I need to put my .class above other classes I need in the classloader tree. So when my valve executes I get ClassNotFoundException for my User class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by implement a SOAPHandler class. I was able to intercept the SOAP message, add headers parameters and when that SOAP message arrived at Application2 I extracted those headers information implement the same SOAPHandler.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "outgoing request" I understand this to be the 'Response'. I would suggest you also use a Servlet Filter to make your change in Application1 after it has gone through the normal filter/processing chain.

i.e.:

```
filterchain.doFilter(request, response);
//code here...
```

I don't see how you could modify the request / response parameters with [Apache Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html).

Comment: Filters only intercept incoming resquest and the outgoing response.I wanted to intercept a request that is being made to a JAXWS webservice. Like intercept the request that is coming out of the Application1 before it becomes an incoming request in the Application2. I was able to accomplish my goal by implement a SOAPHandler, that way I was able to intercept the SOAP message, add header parameters and when that SOAP message arrived at my Application2 I extracted those headers.